# elasticsearch ttl vs daily dropping tables

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I understand that there are two dominant patterns for keeping a rolling window of data inside elasticsearch:

1. creating daily indices, as suggested by logstash, and dropping old indices, and therefore all the records they contain, when they fall out of the window
2. using elasticsearch's TTL feature and a single index, having elasticsearch automatically remove old records individually as they fall out of the window

Instinctively I go with 2, as:

- I don't have to write a cron job
- a single big index is easier to communicate to my colleagues and for them to query (I think?)
- any nightmare stream dynamics, that cause old log events to show up, don't lead to the creation of new indices and the old events only hang around for the 60s period that elasticsearch uses to do ttl cleanup.

But my gut tells me that dropping an index at a time is probably a lot less computationally intensive, though tbh I've no idea how much less intensive, nor how costly the ttl is.

For context, my inbound streams will rarely peak above 4K messages per second (mps) and are much more likely to hang around 1-2K mps.

Does anyone have any experience with comparing these two approaches? As you can probably tell I'm new to this world! Would appreciate any help, including even help with what the correct approach is to thinking about this sort of thing.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with option 1 - i.e. daily dropping of indices.

### Daily Dropping Indices

pros:

- This is the most efficient way of deleting data
- If you need to restructure your index (e.g. apply a new mapping, increase number of shards) any changes are easily applied to the new index
- Details of the current index (i.e. the name) is hidden from clients by using [aliases](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html)
- Time based searches can be directed to search only a specific small index
- [Index templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index-templates.html) simplify the process of creating the daily index.

These benefits are also detailed in the [Time-Based Data Guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/time-based.html), see also [Retiring Data](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/retiring-data.html)

cons:

- Needs more work to set up (e.g. set up of cron jobs), but there is a plugin    ([curator](http://untergeek.com/2014/02/18/curator-managing-your-logstash-and-other-time-series-indices-in-elasticsearch-beyond-delete-and-optimize/)) that can help with this.
- If you perform updates on data then all versions of a document data will need to sit in the same index, i.e. multiple indexes won't work for you.

### Use of TTL or Queries to delete data

pros:

- Simple to understand and easily implemented

cons:

- When you delete a document, it is only marked as deleted. It won’t be physically deleted until the segment containing it is [merged](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/merge-process.html) away. This is very inefficient as the deleted data will consume disk space, CPU and memory.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer is, go with option 1 and simply delete indexes that are no longer needed.

Long answer is it somewhat depends on the volume of documents that you're adding to the index and your sharding and replication settings.  If your index throughput is fairly low, TTLs can be performant but as you start to write more docs to Elasticsearch (or if you a high replication factor) you'll run into two issues.

1. Deleting documents with a TTL requires that Elasticsearch runs a periodic service ([IndicesTTLService](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/v1.4.4/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/indices/ttl/IndicesTTLService.java)) to [find documents](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/v1.4.4/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/indices/ttl/IndicesTTLService.java#L203-L204) that are expired across all shards and [issue deletes](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/v1.4.4/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/indices/ttl/IndicesTTLService.java#L212-L217) for all those docs.  Searching a large index can be a pretty taxing operation (especially if you're heavily sharded), but worse are the deletes.
2. Deletes are not performed instantly within Elasticsearch (Lucene, really) and instead documents are "marked for deletion". A segment merge is required to expunge the deleted documents and reclaim disk space.  If you have large number of deletes in the index, it'll put much *much* more pressure on your segment merge operations to the point where it will severely affect other thread pools.

We originally went the TTL route and had an ES cluster that was completely unusable and began rejecting search and indexing requests due to greedy merge threads.

You can experiment with "what document throughput is too much?" but judging from your use case, I'd recommend saving some time and just going with the index deletion route which is much more performant.